# How to make the price of the product to be dynamically changed in Django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

I'm using Django framework. I've addded product variants like size, color and glass. Now, I need the price to be dynamically changed with selecting product options. The price doesn't change when I'm choosing different options of the product, it remains the same.

Here is my ajax part:

```
$('#size, #color, #glass').on('change', function () {
  const productId = $('#product-id').val();
  const sizeId = $('#size').val();
  const colorId = $('#color').val();
  const glassId = $('#glass').val();

  console.log("Selected values:", productId, sizeId, colorId, glassId); // Log captured values

  if (productId && sizeId && colorId && glassId) {
    calculateUpdatedPrice(productId, sizeId, colorId, glassId);
  }
});

function calculateUpdatedPrice(productId, sizeId, colorId, glassId) {
  const url = `/get_variant/?product_id=${productId}&size=${sizeId}&color=${colorId}&glass=${glassId}`;
  console.log("Fetching price from URL:", url); // Log request URL

  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log("Response data:", data); // Log server response

      const priceElement = document.getElementById('price');
      const sellPriceElement = document.getElementById('sell-price');
      priceElement.textContent = data.price;
      sellPriceElement.textContent = data.price;
    })
    .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
}
```

And product detail :

```
{% for variant in product.variants.all %}
            <p>Size: {{ variant.size.name }}</p>
            <p>Color: {{ variant.color.name }}</p>            
            <p>Glass: {{ variant.glass.name }}</p>
            <p>Price: <span id="price">{{ variant.price }}</span></p>
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            <strong><label for="size" class="form-label">Ölçü:</label></strong>
            <div class="dropdown-wrapper" style="width: 120px;">
                <select class="form-select" id="size">
                    {% for size in sizes %}
                        <option value="{{ size.id }}">{{ size.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <strong><label for="color" class="form-label">Profil Renkleri:</label></strong>
            <div class="dropdown-wrapper" style="width: 120px;">
                <select class="form-select" id="color">
                    {% for color in colors %}
                        <option value="{{ color.id }}">{{ color.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <strong><label for="glass" class="form-label">Cam Renkleri:</label></strong>
            <div class="dropdown-wrapper" style="width: 120px;">
                <select class="form-select" id="glass">
                    {% for glass in glasses %}
                        <option value="{{ glass.id }}">{{ glass.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>    
        </div>

        <!-- Описание товара -->
        <div class="card-body">
            <strong><p class="card-text">Fiyat:  </strong><span id="sell-price">{{ product.sell_ price }}</span> TL</strong></p>
            <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
            <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
            <a href="{% url "cart:cart_add" %}" class="btn btn-dark add-to-cart"
                data-product-id="{{ product.id }}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                Sepete ekle</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            // Update price dynamically based on selected variant
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                const sizeSelect = document.getElementById('size');
                const colorSelect = document.getElementById('color');
                const glassSelect = document.getElementById('glass');
                const priceElement = document.getElementById('price');
                const sellPriceElement = document.getElementById('sell-price');

                sizeSelect.addEventListener('change', updatePrice);
                colorSelect.addEventListener('change', updatePrice);
                glassSelect.addEventListener('change', updatePrice);

                function updatePrice() {
                    // Get selected values
                    const selectedSize = sizeSelect.value;
                    const selectedColor = colorSelect.value;
                    const selectedGlass = glassSelect.value;

                    // Make an AJAX request to get the updated price
                    // Replace the following line with your own implementation
                    const updatedPrice = calculateUpdatedPrice(selectedSize, selectedColor, selectedGlass);

                    // Update the price element
                    priceElement.textContent = updatedPrice;
                    sellPriceElement.textContent = updatedPrice;
                }

                function calculateUpdatedPrice(size, color, glass) {
                    // Implement your logic to calculate the updated price based on the selected variant
                    // Return the updated price
                }
            });
        </script>
        {% endblock  %}
```

Comment: is the request is showing in browser network? any error in browser console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: priceElement is null

Comment: priceElement.textContent = updatedPrice;

Comment: you have multiple `<span id="price">{{ variant.price }}</span>`

Comment: if there is no `price` element it will show TypeError: priceElement is null. if there is so many price elements it will set first element value. see https://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/9jrftdpe/1/

Comment: can you take a look https://jsfiddle.net/rtjam/bsL43okw/2/